# Socket Data Handling -for data packing (TCP)

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I'm working on a socket project. I want to send ~4kb data with TCP. I need to ask a question in here. That is: If I send ~4kb data with TCP, may my data handler function receives this data in one more time? Namely can RECEIVE(server-side) function return 2 times (If I send ~4kb data once)? If I can understand this, I'll start to make my own packet handling system.

Comment: This is a common topic: I cover some of this at http://tiny.cc/io

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks! I'll read this article :)

Comment: The opposite can also occur; multiple sends can result in one receive.  TCP is just a stream with no notion of discrete "messages".  As the others pointed out you need to develop a **protocol** that allows you to discern when a complete message or multiple messages have been received.

Comment: @Idle_Mind "...you need to develop a protocol that..."? Namely I should develop a *protocol over TCP? Is that a function or is that a real socket protocol like UDP-HTTP-TCP?

Comment: You develop a protocol over TCP.  By this I mean a method for you to send a stream of bytes and still be able to determine where discrete messages begin and end.  This can be done with combinations of fixed and/or variable length messages, delimiters, headers, etc..

Comment: @Idle_Mind That's OK. I'll make a system like that (already). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: yes.

TCP transfers a stream of bytes, there is no mention of messages (and their boundaries) in a TCP connection. Even if you send two bytes they can be received in two separate chunks (theoretically of course; it's quite unlikely in practice). So you should put some marks into your data stream. I'd suggest writing a "message header" before every message where the header contains at least length of the following message's body. And take care, the header itself may also be fragmented when receiving.

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a stream protocol. You receive a stream of bytes in the order you sent them. To reconstruct the message you should either prefix every message with the length of the message or use a delimiter to mark end of the message.

I don't know your business requirements but you could use a binary protocol like [MQTT](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/webservices/ws-mqtt/mqtt-v3r1.html) or a text based protocol like [STOMP](http://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html).